# Consider the following output, I want the output as follows

Tags: sql

```
EmployeeID    Name    EmployeeType
----------    ----    ------------
123456        ramesh  Employee_full
3456          ramesh  Contractor
234557        ramu    Employee_full
2354          ramu    Temp_emp
345678        rammy   Employee_full
4568          rammy   Contractor
```

The above is the output of a query, I want this output to be fed as a sub-query so as to get the following output

```
EmployeeID    Name    EmployeeType
----------    ----    ------------
123456        ramesh  Employee_full
3456          ramesh  Contractor
345678        rammy   Employee_full
4568          rammy   Contractor
```

I need to remove both the records of the employee named `ramu`. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: no... where is your attempt?

Comment: If you just need to filter out `ramu`, use `WHERE Name <> 'ramu`'.  Otherwise, we'll need some more information.

Comment: Wait, so you know *sub-queries* but not basic `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: Hi all I know it was stupid, I modified my earlier query to get the ouput, was too stressed out and posted a stupid question here. Thanks a lot all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you didnt say any condition then it will be easy doing it like that

```
      SELECT * FROM your_table where Name <> 'ramu'
```

- Or i guess you want exclude `Name` where `employeetype` have `Temp_emp`

then use this

```
     SELECT * FROM table1 where Name not in 
     ( select Name from table1 where EmployeeType  = 'Temp_emp')
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00449e/6)